# Whats wrong with my .htaccess? Still tries to load file as a controller. Custom MVC PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, favicon

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

It tries to load a `/favicon.ico` as a controller because favicon.ico does not exist in my root folder. How would I rewrite the above htaccess to not load favicon.ico as a controller 
but to ignore it?

It is making an extra request which I do not want it to do.

Comment: why would you want to do that?  Your MVC should be handling the `404` for `favicon.ico`

Comment: it does not do 404 it makes a separate request for it

Comment: so how do you handle a request for `/hot-garbage` ?

Comment: if controller is not found it loads index controller by default. So if it is a file request something that ends .ico or .png i do not want it to use it as controller just simply dont load if it does not exist

Comment: ouch... you should throw a 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to your htaccess to ignore rewriting favicon.ico and anything with the extensions in the parens

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ [NC]`

So your htaccess would look like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

Comment: how can i ignore anything like that not only favicon. If I want to load an image like /test.png i dont want test.png to be treated as controller

Comment: fixed.. example includes ignoring multiple file types

Comment: thank you, i modified slightly and it works: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|JPG|gif|png|PNG|ico|pdf|swf|xml|pem)$ [NC]`